# incorrect params in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to, update-attributes

I want to click on dropdown item called "User" and "Admin" and this should update role column in my account table to this value.

```
      %tr
        %td 
          .dropdown
            %button#dropdownMenuLink.btn.btn-outline.btn-sm.dropdown-toggle{"aria-expanded" => "false", "aria-haspopup" => "true", "data-toggle" => "dropdown", :type => "button"}
              =account.role
            .dropdown-menu{"aria-labelledby" => "dropdownMenuButton"}
              .dropdown-item #{link_to "User", account.update_attribute("role", "user")} 
              .dropdown-item #{link_to "Admin", account.update_attribute("role", "admin")}
```

And I get this error:
`` undefined method `to_model' for true:TrueClass Did you mean?  to_yaml ``

Comment: `update_attribute` method returns `true` or `false`, it doesn't return model. Besides, why do you perform `update_attribute` in your view instead of controller, where it should be? It's strongy disadvised.

Comment: Are you aware that the `link_to` method and therefore the `account.update_attribute` methods are evaluated when the view is rendered? This view tries to first sets the account's role to 'user' and then right after to 'admin'. Each time you load that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do update of attributes in controller, not in views. You can use link_to to go to an action and pass additional params.

```
%tr
  %td 
    .dropdown
      %button#dropdownMenuLink.btn.btn-outline.btn-sm.dropdown-toggle{"aria-expanded" => "false", "aria-haspopup" => "true", "data-toggle" => "dropdown", :type => "button"}
        =account.role
      .dropdown-menu{"aria-labelledby" => "dropdownMenuButton"}
        .dropdown-item= link_to "User", path_to_your_action(id: account.id, role: :user) 
        .dropdown-item= link_to "Admin", path_to_your_action(id: account.id, role: :admin)
```

Anyway your controller to handle update and redirect should look like:

accounts_controller.rb

```
def your_action
  @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  if @account.update(role: params[:role])
    redirect_to # <somewhere>
  end
end
```

instead of `link_to`, you'd better use `form_for`.

```
.dropdown-item
  = form_for account do |f|
    = f.hidden_field :role, value: :user
    = f.submit 'User'
```